# Websockets in JEE6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websocket

I want to create a JEE6 application that uses websockets. Is there any library I can use to do so that allows me to use application server's port instead of opening a new port? (Which is out of JEE6 specification as far as I know)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you found solution? I would very appreciate if you share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that most of the JEE6 application servers/servlet containers support websockets in a standard way. But you can actually try to use container-specific functionality. For example Jetty and Glassfish support websockets in their container-specific way.
Here are the links:

1. [Jetty](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty_WTP_Plugin/Jetty_WTP_Websocket_Wizard)
2. [Glassfish](http://antwerkz.com/glassfish-web-sockets-sample/)

There is also [jwebsocket](http://jwebsocket.org/) which I suppose [can be embedded](http://jwebsocket.org/index.htm?page=quickguide/quickguide.htm~qg_server_bundle.htm) into the Tomcat.

Answer (score 3):

There is [JSR-356](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356), more information is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jsr356-1937161.html) that support WebSockets on java EE7.

I made attempt to use reference implementation [Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net/) on Java EE6 but without success. [JSR-365](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=365) depend on [Servlet 3.1](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr340/) which is a part of Java EE7. Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914008/will-javax-servlet-filter-intercept-websocket-messages-java-servlet-api) from Tyrus developer.

This means that it is only possible to use [JSR-365](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=365) on EE7 [compatible](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html) application servers or servers that supports [Servlet 3.1](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr340/) with the help of [Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net/index.html).

Also I checked popular [Atmosphere framework](http://async-io.org/). Probably it would be interesting to look at their [compatibility page](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Supported-WebServers-and-Browsers).