# Will javax.servlet.Filter intercept Websocket messages? (Java Servlet API)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, websocket

When I have a websocket connection, say at "/ws"

Will a regular javax.servlet.Filter on the "/ws" path intercept each message as a regular http request? Will it intercept only the first request (as part of the handshake?)

If no, then, how can I make such a filter for websocket messages?

I don't find any specifics about that in the spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Servlet Filter won't catch WebSocket messages.

Servlet does not support WebSocket protocol at all. Only thing you can do is to register [HttpUpgradeHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpUpgradeHandler.html) (see [HttpServletRequest#upgrade](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#upgrade(java.lang.Class)))and then implement WebSocket protocol on top of that.

Or.. if you want to save some time, take a look at JSR 356 and the implementations, they are working on top of this API. I personally work on [Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net), which is the reference implementation of JSR 356. (It is part of Java EE 7, but you only need Servlet 3.1 API).

Comment: Is it any chance to use Tyrus implementation on EE6 (Websphere 8.0)?

Comment: Will a Servlet Filter run before the WebSocket Handshake or not even then?

Answer (score 1):

> Will it intercept only the first request (as part of the handshake?)

Yes, only the first request, the one that initiates the WebSocket Handshake, is intercepted by the Servlet Filter.